# Android - Loading local html faster

Tags: android, html, android-asynctask, android-assets

I used a WebView to show html in my assets folder `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");`
My question is; 
Is there a way to load the html file faster, or perhaps `doInBackground`?

At the moment I show a progress dialog for 2seconds, just to give time for the html to load... Any work around would help

Comment: `doInBackground` will not load it faster, even if it worked (it actually won't since you have to work with any view on UI thread).  The only way to load it faster in your case is to optimize your HTML, so it loads faster.